# Increasing the text size of tikz-cd labels

Tags: tikz-cd

By default the arrow labels in `tikz-cd` are quite small. When the labels involve subscripts or superscripts, they can become unreadable. How can I increase the label text size for all `tikz-cd` diagrams in my document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your preamble, add

```
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {font = \small}}
```

The default font size appears to be `\scriptsize`. Other options include (from small to larger): `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, and `\normalsize`.

Comment: This seem to be valid too \tiny               
\scriptsize         
\footnotesize       
\small              
\normalsize         
\large              
\Large              
\LARGE              
\huge               
\Huge

Comment: is there a way to get this to have the exact same effect but in a specific diagram, instead of modifying each diagram in the document?

Comment: Yes, put the `every label/.append style...` in the arguments to the `tikzcd` environment, i.e. `\begin{tikzcd}[every label/.append style = {font = \small}]`.