# Make the numbers in subsubscript smaller

Tags: math-mode, tikz-cd, subscripts

Consider the following example. The numbers in the subscript within another subscript which is overall put in `\scriptsize` (default as the labels over the arrows in the diagrams) appear to be too large. I tried this with different fonts yet they all show the same result, so this is not a font issue but an incorrect input of mine.

How should I correctly input this kind of subsubscript so that the numbers could appear in the right size? (The goal is to make the symbols like `f_{c_1}` in the arrow labels looks similar to the normal version as shown in the displayed math. As you can see, for now the number `1` is even bigger than the letter `c` in the arrow label.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
% \usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
% \usepackage{newpxmath}
% \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \bullet & \bullet \\
        \bullet & \bullet
        \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-1]
        \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
        \arrow["{f_{c_1}}", from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \arrow["{f_{c_2}}"', from=2-1, to=2-2]
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
    f_{c_1}, f_{c_2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not that it helps you, but it seems that [tikz-cd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254286/52406) defaults to `\scriptsize`, and that probably makes the subindex and its index having the same font size.

Comment: You might be interested in [How to get an even smaller font size than `\tiny`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57673/5764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, TikZ-CD sets `\scriptstyle` for the so called labels (i.e. nodes along arrows). The first subscript gets `\scriptscriptstyle` … and that's it.

If you want your labels set in the same size as normal math you could just tell TikZ-CD that by setting the font of those label to `\textstyle` – or `\displaystyle` but that doesn't do anything in this example.

I've also added an option to scale these labels down again using `scale` which keeps the math styles and just scales down the whole node, similar on how `\scalebox` would do.

By default, every label gets the style `default label scaling` with `scale = 0.7`. You'd need to use `scale = 1/.7` to revert that which to me is uncomfortable because TeX/TikZ might not revert is properly due to imprecisions. You could also use `shift only` in front of `scale={#1}` to reset any rotating, slanting and scaling but that might mess with labels that are `sloped`.
Instead, the `scale labels` key simply overwrites `default label scaling` with a no-op ands adds the desired scaling.

However, this can only be done once as the second example shows, here they stack again.

Though, I don't think this should be a problem because diagrams with differently scaled labels are going to be ugly anyway.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
  default label scaling/.style={scale=.7},
  labels={default label scaling},
  labels in textstyle/.style={
    labels={font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\textstyle},
    inner sep=+0.7ex}},
  scale labels/.style={
    default label scaling/.code=, % disable default scaling
    labels={scale={#1}}}}
% \usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
% \usepackage{newpxmath}
% \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[labels in textstyle]
    \bullet & \bullet \\
    \bullet & \bullet
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-1]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
    \arrow["{f_{c_1}}", from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["{f_{c_2}}"', scale labels=1, from=2-1, to=2-2] % removes scale=.7
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
    f_{c_1}, f_{c_2} \quad \scriptstyle f_{c_1}, f_{c_2}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[labels in textstyle, scale labels=.5] % .5, not .7 * .5
    \bullet & \bullet \\
    \bullet & \bullet
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-1]
    \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
    % the following keep scale = .5 from the environment's setting
    \arrow["{f_{c_1}}" , scale labels= .5, from=1-1, to=1-2] % .5 *  .5
    \arrow["{f_{c_2}}"', scale labels=2,   from=2-1, to=2-2] % .5 * 2
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to set the `scale=0.7` as default, only using other scale factor when explicitly given otherwise?

Comment: @Jinwen Depens, do you want all labels of one or all diagrams to use `scale=0.7` unless stated otherwise or do you want `scale labels` act as if you have writen `scale labels=0.7`?

Comment: I meant the first one: to use `scale=0.7` unless stated otherwise. To achieve such a key-value interface with the expl3 mechanism is known to me, but I'm not familiar with the PGF key handling system.

Comment: @Jinwen It's not really a problem with PGFKeys either. I'm just wondering how to deal with the stacking of the `scale`ing. For most simple labels, `shift only` is probably good enough. For most simply diagrams, `scale labels` as defined in my updated answer should be good to go, too, because I would use it only on the environment and not individually.

Answer (score 0):

As @Werner mentioned in a comment to the question, the right thing to do in this case seems to be (in one way or another) scaling the normal version.

An example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \bullet & \bullet \\
        \bullet & \bullet
        \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-1]
        \arrow[from=1-2, to=2-2]
        \arrow["{\displaystyle\widehat{f}_{c_1}}"{scale=.75}, from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \arrow["{\displaystyle\widehat{f}_{c_2}}"'{scale=.75}, from=2-1, to=2-2]
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
    f_{c_1}, f_{c_2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]