# How to position xy-pic diagrams

Tags: diagrams

I want to position the below diagram more to the center of my page. It shows it to left of my page.

```
\begin{xy}
     (0,20)*+{A}="a"; 
    (20,20)*+{B}="b";
     (20, 0)*+{C}="c";
     {\ar         "a";"b"}?*!/_8pt/{f};
     {\ar    "a";"c"}?*!/^6pt/{h};
     {\ar "b";"c"}?*!/_8pt/{g};
\end{xy}
```

Comment: Also does anyone know how to change h to $f\circ g$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context, you can enclose the diagram in `\[...\]` to have it behave as displayed math. You can change `h` to `f\circ g` in the label but you need to adjust the label spacing slightly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[arrow,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{xy}
     (0,20)*+{A}="a"; 
    (20,20)*+{B}="b";
     (20, 0)*+{C}="c";
     {\ar         "a";"b"}?*!/_8pt/{f};
     {\ar    "a";"c"}?*!/^12pt/{f\circ g};
     {\ar "b";"c"}?*!/_8pt/{g};
\end{xy}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, you might consider switching to `tikz-cd`, which fixes many spacing issues in `xy` and has much more intuitive code, as well as having many more options.

The default for arrow labels is `\scriptstyle`, so you need `labels = {font = \normalsize}` to have the larger labels. Remove that bit of code for the default labels. But also, see `@Qrrbrbirlbel`'s comment below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5cm, column sep=1.5cm, labels = {font = \normalsize}]
A\arrow[r, "f"]\arrow[rd, "f\circ g"'] & B\arrow[d, "g"]\\
& C
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just doing `labels={font=}` should be enough to remove the `\scriptstyle`. It uses the font key to change [`\everymath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667175).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Good point. Though for a beginner it might be better to include `\normalsize` to make it more obvious how to change, for example, to `\footnotesize` or `\large`.